# Setting image as div background with inline-styles. React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

I'm triying to import an image from my resources folder and then set it as `background-image` in a div. See what's I'm doing.

```
import candidatePortrait from "../../../../../images/candidatePortrait.jpg";

<div
    className="candidate-photo"
    style={{
      backgroundImage: props.photo
        ? `url("${props.photo}")`
        : `${candidatePortrait}`
    }}
  />
```

I know that my folder path is good but I don't know how to set it as backgroundImage. See my div style. Thanks!

Comment: you are using qoutes `""` instead of template literals `\`\``

Comment: I tried it `url(${Background})` but not worked

Comment: Oh no, what the hell, now it's working.. sorry for that, how can I close this?

Comment: backgroundImage: `url(${Background})`